# Simulate Cassandra DB timeout

Tags: cassandra, connection-timeout, cassandra-4.0

I am working with a K8s environment running application (WEB API/interface) that interacts with a Cassandra database cluster. I need to simulate network latency or introduce delays specifically for responses from the Cassandra cluster to one of my Kubernetes pods.
I cannot touch Cassandra DB cluster or specific apache pods (limitation due to lab usage).

Cassandra version:
`$ nodetool version ReleaseVersion: 4.1.1 $`

Easiest way would be to use "tc"(traffic control) within K8s POD, but it's not available, and there is no possibility to install it (install package comes from R&D and extra development would be needed for that.

As an alternative approach, I attempted to adjust the "cas-q.request.timeout.ms" parameter to 1ms and introduced extra load to increase the likelihood of timeouts, but no success.

Maybe there is a way to introduce some latency outside of the K8s POD, or some other methods that I did not consider.